# CartoDB coordinate format

Tags: javascript, carto, sql

i try to send geocode from my tracker to cartodb. It seems like that my coordinate or my sql statement are wrong.

This is the Tracker format: ddmm.mmmmm

```
Formatting: 
    var val;
    val = parseFloat(geo);
    var dd =  parseInt(val / 100);
    var mmmm = val % 100;
    var res = dd +(mmmm /60);

SQL:
 sql.execute("INSERT INTO test_table(the_geom, imei) VALUES (ST_SetSRID(ST_Point("+info['longitude']+", "+info['latitude']+"),4326),"+info['imei'] +")")
```

Did i do something wrong?

Answer (score 1):

That might be caused by the quotes of the query in the content of the sql.execute() operation.

The next line is an extract of an [CARTO.js example](http://bl.ocks.org/oriolbx/8aa16503402bd37fc781) that use variables within a SQL query, notice that in order to add the javascript variables within the SQL query (wrapped in double quotes), it use single quotes before and after adding the javascript variables:

`sql.execute("WITH point as(SELECT ST_SetSRID(ST_Point('" + lon + "','" + lat + "'),4326)`

Comment: Hello, sorry i forget to say carto gets the data but the coordinates are a little bit wrong. It seems like that the coordinates has a offset from 10 m.